# Replace European chars using REGX_EXP in DB2

Tags: regex, db2, ibm-midrange, informatica, db2-400

I have to replace European(special) characters with **'@'** from email id in DB2.
**Characters**- §, Ö, Ã, У, ί, Ξ, Þ

Sample Data:-
**emailid**

```
adb@yu.com
ads§mnm.com
vbnÖss.com
ddУrr.com
weίsd.com
ftΞvg.com
```

I want output like:-

```
adb@yu.com
ads@mnm.com
vbn@ss.com
dd@rr.com
we@sd.com`
ft@vg.com
```

I have tried like this-
**regexp_replace(emailid,'§|Ö|Ã|У|ί|Ξ|Þ','@')**
But it is not working , for У,ί,Ξ these 3 chars and giving error regx_exp is not valid.

Can you please help me how can i replace all 3 chars from emailid column in DB2.

Comment: What's your Db2 version and platform? The [following](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=a5faa85caed23fece8d9b47dde5620a5) works well on Db2 11.1.

Comment: AS400, its not working

Comment: It works on my 7.4. Ask your admin to check, if International Components for Unicode (ICU) option is installed (it's a prerequisite). Open a Case with IBM Support, if it doesn't work still.

Comment: You could use a more robust solution by giving the exact list of the characters you want to keep and invert it with ^ : `regexp_replace(emailid,'[^a-zA-Z.]+','@')`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to match the following pattern and replace with `@`.

**Pattern**

```regex
[^\w.]
```

**Explanation**

- `[^` Match a character that is not (`^`) in this character set

  - `\w` Word character includes *A-Z*, *a-z* and *0-9*
  - `.` Literal period, does not need to be escaped as it's in a set
- `]` End of character set

See the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/EEBpDs/1).